# keep content webpage after submitting form with file attachment on that page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developping a private webpage for members. On this page a member can view some of its personal data (retrieved from the database) and can also submit a file.

When the user submits the file (and therefore a php file 'upload_file.php' is called) how to 'get back' to the member page with all the retrieved database values and executed javascript functions IF its required that this webpage should also work on older browser versions that do not support HTML5;
I know how to implement the file upload function by means of javascript/jquery + HTML5 ([How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery); [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)), but as said I want to support older browser (HTML 5 unsupported) versions as well.

My simplified html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">
       <label for="file">Filename:</label>
       My name: <input type="text" id="myname" name="myname" value=""><br>
       <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
       <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for ajax here.  nor jQuery.

You can place your file upload in an iframe and submit this iframe.

especially when you need old browser support.

Comment: thnx. I just tried that (by looking at some example code from the internet; I have liitle experience with using iframes), pls see my updated text above. Unfortenately my code doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just post your upload form to target="_blank" and close that response page after returning or use an iframe.